# How to build an inventory from transactions in access

Tags: excel, ms-access, inventory

I am trying to determine the cost of goods for each good and date in my inventory including interest payments based on transactions in my system. I receive the information regarding the transactions from an MS Sql server and I am limited to MS Access and Excel to analyze the data.

I have built a query that gives me following fields:

```
goodsCode | transactionDate | transactionQuantity | transactionPrice | transactionType
```

And as a further Input I have

```
interestRate
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
goodsCode | transactionDate | inventoryBalance | unitCost
```

I was able to reproduce the problem for a single good in Excel by adding some variables that took their inputs from the previous and current row in the following way (with t being the current row and t-1 the previous row):

```
inventoryChange(t) = 
    IF(transactionType = "Sale" OR "SaleReturn"): + transactionQuantity(t) 
    ELSE: - transactionQuantity(t) 

inventoryBalance(t) = inventoryBalance(t-1) + inventoryChange(t)

daysPassed(t) = transactionDate(t-1) - transactionDate(t) 

inventoryCost(t) = inventoryValue(t-1) * ((1+interestRate)^daysPassed(t) - 1)

referencePrice(t) = 
    IF(transactionType = "Purchase" OR "PurchaseReturn"): transactionPrice(t)
    ELSE: unitCost(t-1) * (1+interestRate)^daysPassed(t)

inventoryValue(t) = inventoryValue(t-1) + inventoryCost(t) + inventoryChange(t) * referencePrice(t)

unitCost(t) = inventoryValue(t) / inventoryBalance(t)
```

The result I am looking for is a table where this operation takes place for every good so I can analyze the individual goods in further queries or pivot tables. I am new to Access so I do not know which method to use, i.e. is it necessary to loop through every row to perform this operation? If so, what is the best way to do this, in SQL or in VBA.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

EDIT:

I've though a bit about the solution and one way might be to make a second query that is shifted by one row to do this operation (this would be how I would efficiently handle the problem in Matlab).

Now the problem that remains is how to address the rows where the goodsCode switches. I think SQL would let me iterate through every goodsCode, but Access is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Crosstab query in Access might be something that can help you. I think you can't do crosstab query in SQL.

Comment: Hi Remi, I'm afraid Crosstab query in access, but it is very limited for this purpose and is used to make simple calculations, e.g. sum or count.